# Como usar o required e verificar se os dados já foram inseridos?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Como é que eu posso fazer com que seja obrigatório ao utilizador preencher todos os campos do formulário?
 Eu tentei pôr required no código mas por algum motivo não aparece a mensagem que costuma aparecer quando ponho o mesmo código num ficheiro HTML.

Código index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Site</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Formulário Agenda -->
<div class="modal fade" id="agenda" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
<form name="calendario" id="calendario" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h2 class="text-uppercase align-self-end text-center">Agendamento</h2>
<hr class="divider">
</div>

        <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-4">Primeiro Nome</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pnome" required="required">
            </div>        
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-4">Número de telemóvel</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numerotmv" required="required">
            </div>        
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-4">Local da Sessão</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localsessao" required="required">
            </div>        
        </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="data" type="date" required="required">
<span class="form-label">Data</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" name="hora" type="time" required="required">
<span class="form-label">Hora</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
   <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
<button type="submit" onClick="verificarAgendamento()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Agendar</button>
</div>  
</div>      
    </form>
</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<script>
function verificarAgendamento(){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "agendamento.php",
data: $("#calendario").serialize(),
success: function(resultado){
if(resultado==0){  
  alert("Erro");  
  }else{
  alert("Agendamento feito com sucesso");
  }
return false;
}
});
$('#calendario')[0].reset();
return false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Código agendamento.php:

```
<?php

include("conecta.php");

$pnome=$_POST['pnome'];
$numerotmv=$_POST['numerotmv'];
$localsessao=$_POST['localsessao'];
$data=$_POST['data'];
$hora=$_POST['hora'];

$pesquisaUsuario = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conexao,"
SELECT nome FROM agendamento
WHERE numerotmv = '$numerotmv'
"));


if($pesquisaUsuario >0){
echo 1;
}else{
mysqli_query($conexao, "insert into agendamento (pnome, numerotmv, localsessao, data, hora) values('$pnome','$numerotmv', '$localsessao','$data','$hora')");
echo 0;
}



?>
```

Estrutura da minha base de dados:[image: estrutura base de dados]

Obrigado a todos que gastaram o seu tempo precioso ao ler este post para me ajudar. Sou muito grato.

Comment: Pelo que eu pude perceber você esta utilizando jQuery para fazer o envio do formulário via HTTP POST pro seu arquivo PHP. Testei exatamente o código postado e ele me retorna ReferenceError: $ is not defined. você se certificou de fazer a importação correta do jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esteja no evento que você está utilizando pra realizar a requisição. Como você utiliza o evento `onClick`, a função esta sendo chamada independente dos `inputs` estarem ou não preenchidos, sendo assim recomendo que faça as seguintes alterações no seu código:

1. Remova o evento `onClick` do seu `button`:

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Agendar</button>
```

2. Faça a importação do jQuery caso ainda não tenha feito:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

3. Deixe seu javascript dessa forma:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "agendamento.php",
        data: $("#calendario").serialize(),
        success: function (resultado) {
          if (resultado == 0) {
            alert("Erro");
          } else {
            alert("Agendamento feito com sucesso");
          }
          return false;
        }
      });
      $('#calendario')[0].reset();
      return false
    });
```

Em `document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => { })` o formulário é selecionado e é adicionado o evento de `submit`. O segundo parâmetro é o callback que será executado quando o evento for chamado, basicamente é o código da sua função `verificarAgendamento`